# Book(s) dragon turned into a human and cast into a low magic modern world

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read this more recent book series a while ago (within last couple of years). Book was about a dragon who angered another elder dragon and had then got his magic bound, turned into a human, and cast into a modern world. Following he has to figure out how to live in a low magic modern world as a human along with getting his magic back.

Edit:
Found the book title after going back 3 years in my Kindle unlimited history (It was Kindle Unlimited at the time I read it).

Book [*A Prison of Worlds (The Chained Worlds Chronicles Book 1)* By Daniel Ruth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00R9ZBF62)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a physical book or an e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?  The names of any of the characters or places?

Comment: Read as a e-book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the book title after going back 3 years in my Kindle Unlimited history (It was Kindle Unlimited at the time I read it).

The book is [A Prison of Worlds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33952253-a-prison-of-worlds) (The Chained Worlds Chronicles Book 1) By Daniel Ruth.

Comment: Glad you found your book. Don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you'll be able to do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, 48 hours after the question was first posted.